# SQL: find out which values do appear together more often when grouped by another column value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Say we have a dataframe like the one that follows:

```
order   fruit       qty
1       apple       5
1       grape       8
1       peach       3
2       orange      6
2       apple       4
2       raspberry   3
2       peach       2
3       apple       8
3       peach       6
3       orange      3
```

My goal is to get to know what values stored in `fruit` column do coincide more often into the same order. In other words, something like that:

```
f                t
apple/peach      3
apple/orange     2
apple/raspberry  1
orange/raspberry 1
...              ...
```

Is there a simple and smooth way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the table to itself so as to get all fruit pairs from an order. Then aggregate by fruit pair and count.

```
select t1.fruit, t2.fruit, count(*)
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.order = t1.order and t2.fruit > t1.fruit
group by t1.fruit, t2.fruit
order by count(*) desc, t1.fruit, t2.fruit;
```